# Nested modules (packages) with python c api?

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-embedding

How can I create nested modules (packages?) with the python c api?

I would like the client code (python) to be able do something like this:

```
import MainModuleName
import MainModuleName.SubModuleName
```

Instead of currently:

```
import MainModuleName
import MainModuleNameSubModuleName
```

Which imo looks ugly and clutters up the namespace.

Is it possible without having to mess around with file system directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not "mess around" with file system directories. File system directories are how you create submodules, unless you want to be really obscure and have a lot of needless pain.

You want to have a module called `MainModuleName.SubModuleName` and then `MainModuleName` should be a directory with an `__init__.py` file.

A common way of doing C modules is to put all the C-code in modules with names starting in underscore, in this case `_mainmodulename.c`, and then importing them from Python files. This is done so that you only need to implement the things in C that *has* to be in C, and the rest you can do in Python. You can also have pure-Python fallbacks that way. I suggest you do something similar, and create the module structure in Python and then import the classes and functions from C modules with underscore names.

Comment: OK, I will not try to bend python over for my highly aestethic needs :) The underscore scheme seems nice, but does it mean I have to provide python wrappers for all my C functions/classes? Since the users of MainModuleName won't see the _MainModuleName import?

Comment: No, you just import the functions from `_MainModuleName` in `MainModuleName.__init__`, and users of `MainModuleName` can `import X from MainModuleName`.

Comment: I see, for some reason I thought that imported names was included when the module is imported into another module. I implemented this approach and I'm very happy with the result. Tack så mycket!